# In Perl, should a function do the wantarray dance, or can we expect the caller to use map?

Tags: perl, dictionary

On the (much appreciated) [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/) site, I found the [following snippet that trims](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=36684) the spaces from both sides of a string:

```
sub trim {
  @_ = $_ if not @_ and defined wantarray;
  @_ = @_ if defined wantarray;
  for (@_ ? @_ : $_) { s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// }
  return wantarray ? @_ : $_[0] if defined wantarray;
}
```

I don't understand why the author goes to all the trouble of checking wantarray almost every line. Why not just trim the string, and have the programmer use `map` when he is passing an array?

What is the difference between that trim, called like this:

```
my @test_array = ( 'string1', ' string2', 'string3 ', ' string4 ');
my @result = trim(@test_array);
```

Or a simple trim, called like this when one needs to trim an array:

```
my @test_array = ( 'string1', ' string2', 'string3 ', ' string4 ');
my @result = map { trim($_) } @test_array;
```

Comment: why do you want to leave the map to the user while you can abstract it away?

Comment: Related: [trim in Perl](https://plus.google.com/105725977711317285348/posts/ienzxqHJmRe)

Comment: wantarray and similar magic shit are a blight. Don't do clever programming unless you have to. Never to clever APIs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all it's better if you abstract that map away:

```
#e.1.
sub trim
{
    my @ar = @_;
    for (@ar) { s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// };
    return wantarray ? @ar : $ar[0];
}
```

Second, consider the above example and compare it with:

```
#e.2.
sub trim
{
    for (@_) { s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// };
}
```

what's the difference?

e.1. returns a new trimmed array, while e.2. modifies the original array.

Ok now, what does the original cryptic subroutine do?

It auto-magically (yeaah, it's Perl) modifies the original array **if you are not assigning the return value to anything** OR leaves the original array untouched and returns a new trimmed array **if you are assigning the return value to another variable**.

How?

By checking to see if wantarray is defined at all. as long as the function is on the right hand side and the return value is assigned to a variable "defined wantarray" is true (regardless of scalar/array context).

Comment: The author also wants the function to operate on `$_` implicitly if no arguments are passed to the function.

Comment: So, you would recommend to have each function offer to accept both LIST and SCALAR, so the caller does not have to write the map himself? I like the idea, but two things held me off: 1. the overhead when not needed; 2. the copy-pasting of code (4 lines instead of 1) just to handle void/scalar/list context.

Comment: not to accept (anyway your parameters will all go to @_ in the subroutine) but to return. and it can be achieved with return wantarray ? @ar : $ar[0]; statement. the original 4-liner is doing a lot more that taking care of scalar/list as i tried to explained above.

Answer (score 7):

Breaking this down line by line since it hasn't been:

```
sub trim {
  @_ = $_ if not @_ and defined wantarray;
     # if there are no arguments, but a return value is requested
     # then place a copy of $_ into @_ to work on

  @_ = @_ if defined wantarray;
     # if the caller expects a return value, copy the values in @_ into itself 
     # (this breaks the aliasing to the caller's variables)

  for (@_ ? @_ : $_) { s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// }
     # perform the substitution, in place, on either @_ or $_ depending on
     # if arguments were passed to the function

  return wantarray ? @_ : $_[0] if defined wantarray;
     # if called in list context, return @_, otherwise $_[0]
}
```

I agree that the code gets a bit tedious with all of the `wantarray` checks, but the result is a function that shares a level of flexibility with Perl's builtin functions.  The net result of making the function "smart" is to clean up the call site (avoiding looping constructs, temp variables, repetition, ...) which depending on the frequency the function is used can meaningfully improve code readability.

The function could be simplified a little bit:

```
sub trim {
    @_ = @_ ? @_ : $_ if defined wantarray;

    s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @_ ? @_ : $_;

    wantarray ? @_ : shift
}
```

The first two lines can be rolled into one, since they are doing the same thing (assigning to `@_`) just with different source values.  And there is no need for the outer `return ... if defined wantarray` check at the end, since returning a value in void context doesn't do anything anyway.

But I would probably change the last line to `wantarray ? @_ : pop` since that makes it behave like a list (last element in scalar context).

Once all is said and done, this allows the following calling styles to be used:

```
my @test_array = ( 'string1', ' string2', 'string3 ', ' string4 ');

my @result = trim @test_array;
my $result = trim $test_array[0];
trim @test_array; # in place trim
```

and even still supports the call site loop:

```
my @result = map trim, @test_array;
```

or more verbosely as:

```
my @result = map trim($_), @test_array;
```

and it can be used inside a while loop similar to `chomp`

```
while (<$file_handle>) {
    trim; 
    # do something
}
```

Opinions about dwimmery in Perl are mixed.  I personally like it when functions give me the flexibility to code the caller in a way that makes sense, rather than working around a function's rigid interface.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the author wanted to mimic the behavior of the standard `chomp` function. There is no need to do this in your own function.

> ```
> man perlfunc 
> chomp VARIABLE 
> chomp( LIST ) 
> chomp
> ```
>
> [...] If you chomp a list, each element is chomped. [...]

Comment: i guess wantarray has nothing to do with this kind of behavior in chomp

Comment: chomp is modifying the originial array so it could be as simple as: sub chomp { for (@_) s/blah/blah/}

Comment: Yup, you are right. Indeed `wantarray` becomes defined when caller expects a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is exactly how [Text::Trim](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTrim) is implemented. See its description on various use-cases. Plays with `wantarray` allows to distinguish various contexts and implement different semantics for each.

Personally I prefer just single semantics as it is easier to understand and use. I would avoid using `$_` default variable or modification in place, in line with Nylon Smile's example 1.